Show/hide password component does not work
I am trying to implement the show/hide password functionality when a user logs in. I followed the instructions from Magento, https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/howto/show-hide-password-checkbox/, but they don't seem to work.
I looked at this ticket as well, customer/account/login Showpassword checkbox doesnt work, but it didn't help much.
I am able to get the checkbox to display, but when I click it, it doesn't do anything.

It looks like it's hitting the JS as it should ...

Here is my code. What am I missing?
app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml
<div class="block block-customer-login">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong id="block-customer-login-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Registered Customers')) ?></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading">
    <form class="form form-login"
          action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>"
          method="post"
          id="login-form"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset login" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
            <div class="field note"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('If you have an account, sign in with your email address.')) ?></div>
            <div class="field email required">
                <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="login[username]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getUsername()) ?>"
                        <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()): ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?>
                           id="email" type="email" class="input-text"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>"
                           data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}'
                           data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
                           placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field password required">
                <label for="pass" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="login[password]" type="password"
                        <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()): ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?>
                           class="input-text" id="pass"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                           data-validate="{required:true}"
                           placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field choice" data-bind="scope: 'showPassword'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary"><button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign In')) ?></span></button></div>
                <div class="secondary"><a class="action remind" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getForgotPasswordUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Forgot Your Password?')) ?></span></a></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Customer/js/block-submit-on-send": {
                "formId": "login-form"
            },
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "showPassword": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/show-password",
                        "passwordSelector": "#pass"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>


https://codedecorator.com/magento-2-show-hide-password.html This extension is free and you can use it to solve your problem..

The reason this does not work on our site is because of the WeltPixel Social Login extension. When I turn this off, I am able to get the show/hide password functionality to work.
We are using an older version of this extension, but it does appear that they may have a fix for this issue from March of 2023.

